# Can I configure a fixed IP address on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, network

Hi is it possible to configure a fixed IP on my iPhone? I'm interesting in something like the location provided my the "apple" menu in OS X.

Comment: IPs are assigned by the router, it has nothing to do with the device. Most routers allow for IP reservations that do just that (usually bound to the device's MAC address).

Comment: Totally agree with @cksum - controlling DHCP by client ID or MAC address is always preferable but sometimes it's nice to pick an IP when the network is saturated or DHCP has no leases left but you can sniff an IP that's unused using other tools.

Comment: @bmike Yeah, that's what I meant when I said "it has nothing to do with the device." ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the network settings:

- Wi-Fi
- join your network if needed
- tap the blue right arrow
- Select Static instead of DHCP/BootP and enter in the fixed IP you prefer

Visit http://help.apple.com/iphone/ if you want pictures to guide you to the network settings part of the settings app.

This only works on Wi-Fi since your carrier issues you an IP address. You could also use a VPN profile to tunnel all traffic to a fixed IP if you had a router / server set up to provide that sort of IP / DHCP to iOS devices.

Comment: Oh right. Forgot about static IPs. Wish you posted this before I made my comment above ;)